# How to simulate Imaging Forward Looking Sonar in Rviz

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am  doing my project on ROS Melodic and  trying to simulate my underwater robot using imaging FLS (Forward Looking Sonar) . But most of the references I have read use gazebo to simulate sonar, whereas I am working on Rviz. So, does anyone know how to simulate this type of sonar in RVIZ ? or does anyone know the mathematical model of this sonar ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378696/how-to-simulate--imaging-forward-looking-sonar-in-rviz/) by [jenanaputra](https://answers.ros.org/users/58305/jenanaputra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But most of the references I have read use gazebo to simulate sonar, whereas I am working on Rviz

seeing most references only discussing Gazebo would make sense, as RViz is not a simulator.

You cannot really simulate anything in RViz, it's the *Robot Vizualiser*, which only visualises data streams going around in your ROS application. Without data, there is nothing to visualise.

For simulation, you'll want to use Gazebo, Webots, CoppeliaSim, etc.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0